# Lipschitz constant of continuous and piecewise linear functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I want to calculate the Lipschitz constant of a continuous and piecewise linear function $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow R$, like this
\begin{equation*}
f(x_1,x_2)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
2x_1+x_2, &\quad\text{if} \quad x_1+x_2\leq 1\\
x_1+1, &\quad\text{if} \quad x_1+x_2>1
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
I guess it is equal to the greatest Lipschitz constant among all pieces. Is there any textbook that contain related theorem?

Comment: Yes, but also check the case in which one point is in each piece.

Comment: @Ramita I don't know how to prove it. I'm looking for a textbook on this issue.

Comment: There is no well known theorem but it is not difficult to prove either. For the above it is $\sqrt{5}$ with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @copper.hat I find a theorem of the vector-valued form for this issue, https://threesquirrelsdotblog.com/2018/03/16/lipschitz-constant-of-piecewise-linear-vector-valued-functions/, and I feel the proof not easy. I want to cite such results, but I can not find any textbook that contain this issue. And it is not proper for me to cite a website.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has lots of structure, so there are many ways of approaching it.
Here is one way:

Note that $f(x_1,x_2) = \min (2 x_1+x_2,x_1+1)$.

To see that the $\min$ of Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz:

Suppose $f_1,...,f_m$ are Lipschitz with rank $L$, then
$f_k(x)-f_k(y) \le L \|x-y\|$ for all $k,x,y$.
Then $\min_i f_i(x)-f_k(y) \le L \|x-y\|$ and choosing $k$ such that
$\min_j f_j(y) = f_k(y)$ we see that
$\min_i f_i(x)-\min_j f_j(y) \le L \|x-y\|$. Swapping $x,y$ shows that $\min_k f_k$ is Lipschitz with rank $L$. (This result is true more generally, but the finite case contains the basic idea.)

Note that $x \mapsto 2x_1+x_2$ has Lipschitz rank $\sqrt{5}$ and
$x \mapsto x_1+1$ has Lipschitz rank $1$, so the smallest $L$ that 
will work is $L= \max(1,\sqrt{5})$.